# OpenCV findContours - 2.4.5 Heap Corruption

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a heap corruption happening with 100% certainty on the findContours function. When I do not use it, everything works fine.

```
unsigned char* UCFromMatUC(cv::Mat& input)
{
    int size = input.size.p[0] * input.size.p[1];
    unsigned char* result = new unsigned char[size];
    memcpy(result, input.data, size);
    return result;
}

unsigned char* CannyEdgeCV(unsigned char* input, int width, int height)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;

    cv::RNG rng(12345);

    cv::Mat inp(cv::Size(width, height), CV_8UC1, input);
    cv::Mat canny_output;
    cv::Mat outp;
    cv::blur(inp, outp, cv::Size(3,3));
    cv::Canny(outp, canny_output, 4.0, 8.0);
    if(canny_output.type()!=CV_8UC1){
        return NULL;
    }

    cv::findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0) );
    cv::Mat drawing = cv::Mat::zeros( canny_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
    for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
    {
        cv::Scalar color = cv::Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
        drawContours( drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, cv::Point() );
    }

    cv::imwrite( "contours.jpg", drawing );

    unsigned char* result = UCFromMatUC(canny_output);

    return result;
}
```

Originally I was only using the canny edge map, but later on I wanted to test the results of the contour functionality.

The Canny Edge works fine, and I get an image as expected, but the findContours (both the one in code and the commented version) fail with a heap corruption error. What causes this?

The entry point for this is the CannyEdgeCV(), and is called with a 640x480 8bit grey image.

Edit: updated code.

Edit2: when I tried to create a minimal example to reproduce this, my code failed at even imread("imagename.bmp"); which was really odd, so I began investigating what might cause this. Now someone else wrote in a corresponding SO question that you cannot mix debug / release mode libraries, so if you are in debug, you have to use debug DLLs, and that worked for me now, I get the expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main culprit is your use of `cv::Mat*` and `new`. This is a Bad Idea. It is unnecessary and often problematic (as you have discovered) to dynamically allocate `cv::Mat` objects. A better solution is to pass them by value or `const` reference, since the underlying image data is refcounted, and `cv::Mat` are shallow copied.

The first specific problem is that you manually assign the `data` member in `CVMatFromUC()`:

```
resultMat->data = input
```

You should not do this. `cv::Mat` has other members which also reference the data location, and you are asking for trouble. If you need to create a `cv::Mat` header for external data, you should create a `cv::Mat` like so:

```
cv::Mat inp(cv::Size(width, height), CV_8UC1, input);   //Create cv::Mat header, no memory copied
```

Also, your type check for `canny_output` is incorrect. `!canny_output.type()` is evaluated first, and implicitly converts to `true`, as does `CV_8UC1`. So the expression is always `true`. The condition you want is: `canny_output.type() != CV_8UC1`

Given this, it turns out that the `CVMatFromUC()` function is unnecessary. An improved version of your function follows:

```
uchar* CannyEdgeCV(uchar* input, int width, int height)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;

    cv::Mat inp(cv::Size(width, height), CV_8UC1, input);   //Create cv::Mat header, no memory copied
    cv::Mat canny_output;
    cv::Mat outp;
    cv::blur(inp, outp, cv::Size(3,3));

    cv::Canny(outp, canny_output, 10.0, 15.0);
    if(canny_output.type()!=CV_8UC1){
        return NULL;
    }

cv::findContours(canny_output, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE );
//cv::findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0) );

    unsigned char* result = UCFromMatUC(&inp);
    return result;
}
```

I should note that it appears that `CannyEdgeCV` returns the same data that it receives, so it may be possible to remove the call to `UCFromMatUC()` and the associated data copy entirely. However, I tried and got memory errors, so there might be other problems lurking elsewhere.

Comment: Err, you are correct about the return type. I originally had it at Canny(outp, inp), thus the inp held the edge map. But when debugging this, I changed it to more variables, causing the wrong return. I implemented your suggestions, but I still get the very same heap corruption. (Updated code in the edit)

Comment: Okay, part of your recommendations were needed to fix this, but the main issue appeared to be the fact that I linked the release libraries from my debug application.

Answer (score 0):

-Change findContours as follows 
findContours(gray, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

- If it doesn't work again, your problem is probabely uninitialized memory. You can try to create new Mat outP2 and clone the original one into this.
- Then use outP2 from the following step:

cv::Canny(*outP2, canny_output, 10.0, 15.0);
...
...