# Corruption of heap - VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv3.1

I have a C++ program that crashes when I run it. I get the following error:

**This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in test1.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.**

The program is used to identify the hand through the camera feed and detect the contours of the hand.

Code:

This is the function where the crash occurs:

```
void showimgcontours(Mat &threshedimg,Mat &original)
{
  vector<vector<Point> > contours;
  vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
  int largest_area = 0;
  int largest_contour_index = 0;
  **findContours(threshedimg, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);** //this will find largest contour
  for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++) // iterate through each contour. 
  {
    double a = contourArea(contours[i], false);  //  Find the area of contour
    if (a>largest_area)
    {
        largest_area = a;
        largest_contour_index = i;                //Store the index of largest contour
    }

  }
//search for largest contour has end

  if (contours.size() > 0)
  {
      //drawContours(original, contours,largest_contour_index, CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), 2, 8, hierarchy);
      //if want to show all contours use below one
      drawContours(original,contours,-1, CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), 2, 8, hierarchy);
  }
}
```

The bold line(findContours) is where the program breaks.

This is where the function is called:

```
    while ((key = waitKey(30)) != 27)
    {
      toggle(key);
      cap >> frame;
      flip(frame, frame, 180);
      cvtColor(frame, hsvframe, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

      inRange(hsvframe, Scalar(H_MIN, S_MIN, V_MIN), Scalar(H_MAX, S_MAX, V_MAX), rangeframe);

      if (domorph)
          morphit(rangeframe);

      if (doblurthresh)
          blurthresh(rangeframe);

      if (showcontours)
          showimgcontours(rangeframe, frame);

      if (showchangedframe)
          imshow("Camera", frame);
      else
          imshow("Camera", rangeframe);

  }
}
```

This function is called when the user presses the key 'c'.
I googled for solutions but didn't find anything that helped.
Someone please help me!

Comment: Where do you populate `contours`?  If `findContours` is what brakes don't you think its code would be important?

Comment: Corruption happens before the memory manager notices it, and it could have happened a long time ago.

Comment: The frame variable is not allocated, please show us more code.

Comment: @NathanOliver findContours is where contours is populated. It's an inbuilt function in opencv..

Comment: @molbdnilo So what can i do to fix it?

Comment: @FedeWar the frame variable is used to read frames from the camera feed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523169/opencv-findcontours-2-4-5-heap-corruption

Comment: you used debug libraries in release, or viceversa. Or you're using OpenCV build with a different compiler then what you're using. Fix your settings and it will work